# I there any functionality through which we can add the bot in a specific channel of a team other than general channel

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams

I want to add a bot in a specific channel of a team. Whenever I add the bot in any channel of a team other than general channel, the bot gets added to the general channel and its shows the text there like - **xyz has added TestingBot to the team**. Whenever I'm adding the bot to a channel other than general, **onTeamsMemberAddedEvent** function is getting invoked but through this function, I'm not able to get the channel name where I installed the bot. Is there any functionality through which I can acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

There's a big different, I think, between adding a TAB to a 'Channel' (which really does add it to the channel) and adding a BOT to a 'Channel'. Different from the Tab, I think the bot is actually installed to the *entire* Team (every channel), which is probably why you're seeing what you're seeing.